# Dominated by compact operator implies compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Given a Hilbert space $H$, a projection $P\in B(H)$ and a compact operator $T\in B(H)$ how does one conclude that $P\leq T$ implies $P$ compact?

I seem to recall that one can apply the fact that ideals in $B(H)$ are hereditary, but I have forgotten the steps in this reasoning.

Comment: If an argument without operator theory is fine: restricting T to the range of P will make T invective + bounded below. Sine R(P) is closed + T compact you find that R(P) is finite dimensional and P is compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that if $P \le T$ then
$$ \|Pu\|^2 = (Pu,Pu)= (Pu,u) \le (Tu,u) \le \|Tu\| \|u\|, \tag 1 $$
for all $u \in H$. Let $(u_n)$ be a bounded sequence in $H$. Since $T$ is compact, there is an increasing sequence of indices $(k_n)$ such that $(Tu_{k_n})$ converges. It follows from (1) that $(Pu_{k_n})$ is Cauchy in $H$ and thus converges.

Comment: Many thanks to you and all the others for some excellent answers!

Answer (score 4):

More general statement is true. If $0\le B\le A$ and $A$ is compact, then $B$ is compact. Indeed, the assumption is equivalent to $$\|B^{1/2}x\|^2\le \langle Ax,x\rangle $$ This implies compactness of $B^{1/2}$. Hence $B$ is compact as well.

Comment: How does this inequality imply the compactness of $B^{1/2}$?

Comment: @QuantumSpace If $x_n$ tends to $0$ weakly then $\|Ax_n \|\to 0.$ Hence  $\|B^{1/2}x_n\|\to 0.$ Another explanation could be: by the minimax principle the singular values of $A^{1/2}$ dominate the singular values of $B^{1/2}.$ Thus the singular values of $B^{1/2}$ tend to $0,$ which is equivalent to compactness.

Comment: @QuantumSpace: a third argument would be that the inequality shows that the image of the unit ball by $B^{1/2}$ is inside the image of the unit ball by $A^{1/2}$. As $A^{1/2}$ is compact, the closure of the image of the unit ball by $B^{1/2}$ is a closed subset of a compact set and thus compact.